# why it is displaying object object not content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me why it is showing object .not displaying content
in jquery,I am just making simple demo .

http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/19/

```
for(var index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
{
    var currentWord = words[index];
    var currentLength = tenLengthString.length;    
    if(((currentLength + currentWord.length + ((currentLength > 0) ? 1: 0))) > 30)
    {        
      html+=  $('.RLTLeftDiv').append('<div   style=width:100%; clear:both; line-height:200%;><div style=width:60%; float:left;  ><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style=width:40%; float:left; text-align:right; ><b>'+ count +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div>')+$('.RLTRightDiv').append(tenLengthString);

        console.log(tenLengthString);
        count++;
        tenLengthString = currentWord;        
    } else {
        if(currentLength > 0)
            tenLengthString += " ";    
        tenLengthString += currentWord;
    }    
    if(index == words.length - 1){
      console.log(tenLengthString);
       html+='<div>'+tenLengthString+'</div>';

    }        
}
$("#test").html(html)
```

Comment: because `$(..)` returns a jQuery object.... not a string

Comment: You should read http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you wanted, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/21/

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/22/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/17/ i want to see look like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using jQuery objects in string concatenation which will give the result as `[object Object]`

```
var $cp = $('<div><div style="width:22%; float: left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTLeftDiv"><div style="width:100%; clear:both; line-height:200%;"><div style="width:60%; float:left;"><b class="time">hours :minutes:seconds</b></div><div style="width:40%; float:left; text-align:right;"><b><span class="count"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div></div><div style="width:78%; float:left; font-size:18px; line-height:200%;" class="RLTRightDiv"></div></div>')


var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()


if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
}

if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}

if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}


var str = "Ben Nadel reviews the various approaches to Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fansSachin Ramesh Tendulkar is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation, popularly holds the title  among his fans  substring";
var words = str.split(" ");
var tenLengthString = "";
var html = '';
var count = 1;
for (var index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
    var currentWord = words[index];
    var currentLength = tenLengthString.length;
    if (((currentLength + currentWord.length + ((currentLength > 0) ? 1 : 0))) > 30) {
        var $clone = $cp.clone();
        $clone.find('.time').html(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        $clone.find('.count').html(count);
        $clone.find('.RLTRightDiv').html(tenLengthString);
        $("#test").append($clone);
        console.log(tenLengthString);
        count++;
        tenLengthString = currentWord;
    } else {
        if (currentLength > 0) tenLengthString += " ";
        tenLengthString += currentWord;
    }
    if (index == words.length - 1) {
        console.log(tenLengthString);
        $("#test").append('<div>' + tenLengthString + '</div>');

    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/46GLV/)

Comment: what is clone ? what is use clone

Comment: Thanks Sir .good answer I make another way can you increase the count .actually my count is not increase http://jsfiddle.net/9TZhE/4/

Comment: i am using count++ way but it not increasing it is showing 1 1 2 2

Answer (score 1):

The part below makes that. That's an jQuery object, when you cancat to a string, the object's `toString()` method is called which is `[object Object]`.

```
html+=  $('.RLTLeftDiv').append('<div   style=width:100%; clear:both; line-height:200%;><div style=width:60%; float:left;  ><b>'+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" +  seconds+'</b></div><div style=width:40%; float:left; text-align:right; ><b>'+ count +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div></div>')+$('.RLTRightDiv').append(tenLengthString);
```

Comment: can you make fiddle so that I can able to see data as i am able to see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yzaaJ/17/